# Google Data store UI can't use descending index

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I have an app that uses google's datastore.

I have set up an index that uses two properties of some entity, the first one is ascending and the second one is descending.

When I try to filter by the first property (equals some value) and sort descending by the second I get an error saying that I don't have an appropriate index.

But it seems to me that its because when I click the second column it tries to sort ascending as a default and this is what failes.

Is there a way to ask the UI to filter descending (without going through ascending first) ?

Comment: This sounds like a UI problem rather than query/index. What UI are you using for the table & sort control?

Comment: Sounds like he's using https://console.cloud.google.com/datastore

Comment: yes, this is indeed the UI I am using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can use "Query by GQL tab" to test if its UI only problem
2. By default datastore creates 2 single property indexes (asc, desc) for each column, so try to apply required order first and then apply filter.

Comment: yes, you are right about using the GQL tab and it does work.
as for option 2
also you are right about the second option.
My index is on field1 asc, field2 dec - if I  sort by field 1 (asc), then sort by field2 (asc) then sort again by field2 (dec) and only then select the filtering on field1 it does indee work.

Comment: I would appriciate it If you could better explain why does first sorting and then filtering works.